# imposm stops during import

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox

I am trying to develop an application where I want to include openstreetmaps. I decided to try mapbox for this.
I am trying to import data from a osm.pbf file. I have a multiprocessor system capabable of doing a lot of work but in the middle of the import it just seem to stop working. Do I just have to wait or is there an error?

```
ubuntu@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:~/Documents/mapbox-osm-bright-5f237ac/shp$ sudo imposm -U postgres -d osm -m /home/ubuntu/Documents/mapbox-osm-bright-5f237ac/imposm-mapping.py --read --write --optimize --concurrency 10 --cache-dir /mnt/cache --overwrite-cache --deploy-production-tables /mnt/cc/sweden-latest.osm.pbf
loading /home/ubuntu/Documents/mapbox-osm-bright-5f237ac/imposm-mapping.py as mapping
password for postgres at localhost:
[11:30:54] ## reading /mnt/cc/sweden-latest.osm.pbf
[11:30:54] coords: 17545k nodes: 350k ways: 2506k relations: 17k (estimated)
[11:32:02] coords: 26272k nodes: 101k ways: 28k relations: 0k
```

Then I press Ctrl-C after a long time

```
^CProcess CacheWriterProcess-3:: 101k ways: 28k relations: 0k
Process CacheWriterProcess-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
Process ParserProgress-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    self.run()
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imposm/reader.py", line 123, in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imposm/reader.py", line 123, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    data = self.queue.get()
    data = self.queue.get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 117, in get
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 117, in get
    res = self._recv()
    res = self._recv()
KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imposm/util/__init__.py", line 54, in run
    log_statement = self.queue.get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 117, in get
Process CacheWriterProcess-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    res = self._recv()
KeyboardInterrupt
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imposm/reader.py", line 123, in run
    data = self.queue.get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 117, in get
    res = self._recv()
KeyboardInterrupt
Process CacheWriterProcess-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imposm/reader.py", line 123, in run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/imposm", line 9, in <module>
    data = self.queue.get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 117, in get
    load_entry_point('imposm==2.5.0', 'console_scripts', 'imposm')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imposm/app.py", line 253, in main
    res = self._recv()
KeyboardInterrupt
    reader.read(arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imposm/reader.py", line 88, in read
    parser.parse(filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imposm/parser/simple.py", line 62, in parse
    return self.parse_pbf_file(filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imposm/parser/simple.py", line 73, in parse_pbf_file
    return self._parse(filename, PBFMultiProcParser)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imposm/parser/simple.py", line 140, in _parse
    time.sleep(0.001)
KeyboardInterrupt
Process Process-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imposm/parser/simple.py", line 113, in parse_it
    parser.parse(input)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imposm/parser/pbf/multiproc.py", line 70, in parse
    pos_queue.put(pos)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 311, in put
    if not self._sem.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Now just working 2-3% and never seem to finnish, any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of a bug in imposm. To install a patch to fix it:

```
pip install https://github.com/omniscale/imposm-parser/tarball/master
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be circumvented by downloading the unpackaged [OSM-XML](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) file.

Imposm has a problem reading the [PBF](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF) format on certain occasions. But the unpackaged [OSM-XML](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) file does the trick.

In denmark, it is [pbf-file](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/denmark-latest.osm.pbf) (166 MB) vs. [osm-xml-file](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/denmark-latest.osm.bz2) (261 MB, 4.4 GB, decompressed)

```
root@drake:/mnt/disk/maps# imposm -U postgres -d osm -m /usr/local/share/maps/style/osm-bright-master/imposm-mapping.py --cache-dir cache  --read --write --optimize --deploy-production-tables denmark-latest.osm --overwrite-cache
Enabling Shapely speedups.
loading /usr/local/share/maps/style/osm-bright-master/imposm-mapping.py as mapping

[14:53:01] ## reading denmark-latest.osm
[14:53:01] coords: 22391k nodes: 447k ways: 3198k relations: 22k (estimated)
[14:58:38] coords: 15171k nodes: 33k ways: 1587k relations: 6k
[14:58:39] reading took 5 m 37s
[14:58:39] ## dropping/creating tables
[14:58:39] ## writing data
[14:58:47] relations: 6k/6k
[14:58:51] relations: total time 12s for 6783 (562/s)
[15:08:18] ways: 1587k/1587k
[15:08:19] ways: total time 9 m 28s for 1587006 (2793/s)
[15:08:27] nodes: 32k/33k
[15:08:28] nodes: total time 8 s for 33279 (3805/s)
[15:08:28] ## creating generalized tables
[15:08:57] generalizing tables took 28s
[15:08:57] ## creating union views
[15:08:57] creating views took 0 s
[15:08:57] ## creating geometry indexes
[15:09:18] creating indexes took 21s
[15:09:18] writing took 10m 39s
[15:09:18] ## optimizing tables
Clustering table osm_new_mainroads
Clustering table osm_new_buildings
Clustering table osm_new_mainroads_gen1
Clustering table osm_new_mainroads_gen0
Clustering table osm_new_amenities
Clustering table osm_new_waterareas_gen1
Clustering table osm_new_waterareas_gen0
Clustering table osm_new_motorways_gen0
Clustering table osm_new_aeroways
Clustering table osm_new_motorways
Clustering table osm_new_transport_points
Clustering table osm_new_railways_gen0
Clustering table osm_new_railways_gen1
Clustering table osm_new_landusages
Clustering table osm_new_waterways
Clustering table osm_new_railways
Clustering table osm_new_motorways_gen1
Clustering table osm_new_waterareas
Clustering table osm_new_places
Clustering table osm_new_admin
Clustering table osm_new_barrierways
Clustering table osm_new_minorroads
Clustering table osm_new_barrierpoints
Clustering table osm_new_landusages_gen1
Clustering table osm_new_landusages_gen0
Vacuum analyze
[15:09:53] optimizing took 35s
[15:09:53] imposm took 16m 52s
```